# Can't run python code through VS Code. Can't open file ptvsd_launcher.py [Errno 22] Invalid Argument

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-python

VSCode was working perfectly a few days ago before this started happening. Attempting to run any python code through VSCode (with or without debugging) Results in this error in the terminal

`can't open file '"c:/Users/Rastus22/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.5.17517/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py"': [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

A little after the error shows I get a message telling me there was a timeout waiting for the debugger. There aren't any errors in the python itself, currently testing with a file that contains only a print statement. My only other extension is the Darkula theme.

I've tried reinstalling the Python extension and resetting the launch.json file as well as my settings.json file. I've also tried copying over a known good copy of launch and settings file from a different machine and had no luck.
I can't really seem to find anyone else online with the same issue either.

Comment: I remember seeing this issue before, can you try uninstalling the extension, then manually downloading v. `2019.4` and see if the issue persists?

Comment: I'm experiencing this too after the most recent update `1.34.0`. This is the 4th time the debugger has burned me after an update that I'm not going to be on the cutting edge for VSCode anylonger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downgrading to the 2019.4 fixed the issue completely. Thanks to Samuel Cooper for this answer.

Steps to downgrade:

1. Make sure the Python extension is installed.
2. Hit the "manage" button on the extension.
3. "Install another version"
4. Search for the version you want to move to. I downgraded to version 2019.4.12954

Comment: I'd like to point out that the `manage` button is the tooltip that shows when you click the `gear / settings` button